# EventHandlers overriding each other? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a context menu which activated on right click of a node in my JavaFX application. Originally I just had one menu item, but I decided to add another. When I added another, the second menu item worked but the first menu item stopped working. Here was my code:

```
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
        MenuItem hyperlink = new MenuItem("Hyperlink...");
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(delete, hyperlink);

        //handles deletion
        webView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
                    contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        //handles hyperlink
        webView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
                    contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    hyperlink.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

I assumed this was because the listeners were overriding each other, so I changed it to *add* event handlers. Here's how I changed the code:

```
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
        MenuItem hyperlink = new MenuItem("Hyperlink...");
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(delete, hyperlink);

        //handles deletion
        webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
                    contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        //handles hyperlink
        webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()){
                    contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    hyperlink.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            //do stuff
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, NOTHING is happening when I right-click the node. Can someone explain why, and what my solution might be?

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of things:

1. Yes, in your first version, the handlers were overriding each other.
2. Direct translation to `addEventHandler` style would use event type `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED`, not `MOUSE_CLICKED`, since `MOUSE_CLICKED` occurs only after the mouse button has been released, thus the `isSecondaryButtonDown()` test always returns `false`—that's why nothing is happening.
3. Instead of detecting mouse presses, you can listen to `CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED` events:

   ```
   webView.setOnContextMenuRequested(new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(ContextMenuEvent e) {
           contextMenu.show(workspace, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
       }
   }
   ```
4. You should set the menu item's action right after its creation, not on each right click:

   ```
   MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
   delete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
       @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent event)
       {
           //do stuff
       }
   });
   ```

   The only thing you need to do on right click is show the context menu, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you duplicating code. Just follow your first approach and do both things inside the same EventHandler.
One more note: Define your ActionEvents for the MenuItems outside of the webView handlers. What you are doing now is every time you click a menuItem you are resetting the ActionEvents. From your code, I can only see that you need to detect the MouseEvent just to show the Context Menu. Which can be done in one `webView.setOnMousePressed(...)`.